# How to change the PerlAuthzHandler cookie name

Tags: perl, apache, cookies

I'd like to change the cookie name generated by PerlAuthzHandler

My apache config looks like this:

```
<Location /aaa/bbb>
  AuthType Express::StaffAuthCookieHandler
  AuthName ExpressStaffAuth
  PerlAuthzHandler Express::StaffAuthCookieHandler->authorize
</Location>
```

On authentication the cookie returned to the client's is named
Express::StaffAuthCookieHandler_ExpressStaffAuth

There's a bug in some older (6.1.3 at least) iPhone safari browsers that corrupts the :: in the cookie name. I could change the package name to remove the :: (ie ExpressStaffAuthCookieHandler) but is there a simpler way to change the cookie's name?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation pods for [Apache::AuthCookie](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache%3a%3aAuthCookie) and [Apache2::AuthCookie](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache2%3a%3aAuthCookie), you should be able to set a cookie name in your Apache config:

```
PerlSetVar ExpressStaffAuthCookieName ExpressStaffAuthCookieHandler_ExpressStaffAuth
```

The links above have a bit more context, but that looks like it should do it.

Note the first part of the directive is your `AuthName`. I don't see any restrictions on the cookie name, so I just stripped out the `::` from the default.